# Android Webview caret disappears

Tags: android, html, cordova, android-webview, caret

I am in the process of testing a hybrid app for Android 4.4+.  The app consists of

- one custom plugin (my own effort)
- the HTML UI created using [Phonon](http://phonon.quarkdev.com/).
- Phonegap CLI v 6.4.2
- My test device is a Huwaei Holly running Android 4.4.2

One of the issues I have run into is the fact that the caret in `textarea` and `input` controls stops working "after a while" and the soft keyboard does not popup when I tap the control.

By dint of some trial and error I pinned down the problem - it happens AFTER the app has displayed at least one vanilla HTML/JS alert box which I am using for my own debugging needs.  Replacing that with a [Phonon.alert](http://phonon.quarkdev.com/docs/dialogs) box - which is simply an overlayed layer of HTML, not a new window as, I imagine, the bog standard alert is - "fixed" the problem.

Very good but the fact that this happens at all still bothers me - I will not use vanilla alerts in my release build but if it happened with alerts it might well happen with something else.

A spot of Googling revealed that is a known issue that appears to have been around for a while.  This SO thread, for instance, suggests the Webview has to be set as being `focussable` and I have run into the same suggestion elsewhere too.

However, it is not at all clear to me just **where** I should do this.  About the only configuration locations I have at my disposal are

- The config.xml file for my Phonegap/Cordova project
- The plugin.xml file for my custom Phonegap/Cordova plugin

The Phonegap docs related to config.xml do not mention anything about `FrameworkLayout`, `android:focussable` etc.

I'd be most grateful to anyone who might be able to either

- explain just where the `android:focussable` bit should go or
- suggest the root cause of the problem.

Comment: after a bit of googling, the simplest solution i could think of is to use this webview setting plugin - https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-webview-setting and extend the same to include focus setting to resolve your issue. Else you may have to take the hard path of embedding cordova enabled webview as described here - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/webview.html

Comment: Did you tried this?